# CFWheels: Create new datasource using code instead of administrative panel

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I have some queries that work fine in my local environment where I have access to the administrative page where can I set the data source and then reference it from my project.

```
http://localhost:8500/CFIDE/administrator/
```

However, problem is that in my production environment, I don't have access to the administrative page. I can't set up a data source that already doesn't exist.

Is there a way to create the data source connection via code and then reference it? Please let me know

Comment: Take a look at the [Admin API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fcf.html). (Keep in mind you still need to be granted access to use it by whomever administers the CF Server).

Comment: Why don't you find someone who does have access and get them to do it?

Comment: Well, I was curious if there is another way. but I guess above seems like the only solution